# Make better shadow gradient issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I use the following code to create the **shadow**.

But my shadow looks ugly. ***I want something like we can see out of MS Windows.*** You can confirm both under the image I have attached.

How it could be done?

Thank you!

```
DropShadowEffect myDropShadowEffect = new DropShadowEffect();
myDropShadowEffect.Color = GetShadowColorValue();
myDropShadowEffect.ShadowDepth = 5;
myDropShadowEffect.BlurRadius = 70;
myDropShadowEffect.Opacity = 0.8;                  
this.Effect = myDropShadowEffect;
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure i even see a dropshadow on the left part of the attached image. Maybe that's part of your issue with it :)

Comment: @Tim Yes Tim. The left part is my ugly shadow )))

Comment: Do you want to draw the shadow outside of the window? You can't do that without cheating :)

Comment: @M.Stramm No no I just want to do my shadow better. I already has code which draws it. But No idea which parameters I have to adjust to get better look of the shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring your Blur Radius down to more like 5 to 7, 70 is huge. I'd also bring down your opacity to like 35 to 50%

Is the on on the left the results of what you get now? Or what you want?

Comment: Sorry but your advice doesn't help :(

Comment: Perhaps it's not clear what you wish you accomplish then exactly?

Comment: Oh right, you want it darker on lower corner? Add .Direction = 315